# How would one get Bitcoin cash from their existing Bitcoin private keys?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I have my bitcoin private key, how would I get bitcoin cash and where would I dump it for real bitcoin?

Comment: Related to your other question on this topic: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57422/how-to-sweep-private-extended-key-from-mycellium-into-coinomi-for-bitcoin-cash-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your private keys to get your Bitcoin Cash on any Bitcoin Cash wallet. I personally moved it to Bittrex since they'll support both after the split so I will automatically get my Bitcoin Cash there. Bittrex will allow trading with Bitcoin Cash right away but it won't allow transactions so you could sell it immediately if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I used the android coinomi app and just select the sweep keys option. FYI, the desktop version does not support sweep.