# How to sweep private extended key from mycellium for bitcoin cash coins?

Tags: private-key, bitcoin-cash, mycelium-wallet, sweep, coinomi

I have my coins stored in mycellium, but when I try to export my private key I get a private extended key. How can I import this into coinomi android wallet? I see there is a sweep option in conomi, but it doesnt state that it supports an extended private key. Do I have to extract my single private keys and import them one at a time into my coinomi android wallet? screenshots would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for the coinomi app importing an extended key, but if you need to extract the private keys from the extended key, you can use http://bip32.org/.

I haven't personally audited this site, but I have used it to browse my private keys associated with a Mycelium HD account. Once you have extracted your private extended key from Mycelium however, I'd recommend archiving that account and making a new one.

The keys can be seen by first entering in the entire extended private key, then choosing a custom derivation path. I've found my Mycelium private keys starting with the custom path m/0/0. From here, you can increment the last part of the path up to 7 before incrementing the middle part of the path.

For example:
m/0/0 ->
m/0/1 ->
m/0/2 ->
m/0/3 ->
m/0/4 ->
m/0/5 ->
m/0/7 ->
m/1/0 ->
m/1/1 ->
...

Edit: I have successfully used the Coinomi app to sweep my unspent outputs from the Mycelium app. I first entered the private extended key into the appropriate box on bip32.org, and I browsed through the custom derivation paths until I found the address that had the unspent output, which also displays the private key. Entering that private key into the Coinomi app allowed me to sweep the balance of Bitcoin Cash that was in those unspent outputs.

Comment: custom m/0/0  isnt matching any of my known addresses it seems. did you do this manually and guess to find the correct one? is there a way to search in mycelium for the derivation path?

Comment: I had to manually iterate through the m/0/0 -> m/0/7 etc in order to find the address with the unspent output. Starting with m/0/0 you should be able to find address matches for that particular HD account. Double check to make sure your private extended key is right.

You can also select the account from the accounts tab, hit the "Sign Message" menu option to view all your public addresses associated with the account.

Comment: i have over 40 public keys. does it always start at m/0/0 and increments up from there by m/0/1  ?

Comment: The account I used this tactic with had 12 keys, and I was able to find each used address starting with m/0/0, incrementing to m/0/7, at which point I had to find the rest starting at m/1/0 and my last key was found at m/1/3. I'm not certain but I would guess yours starts at m/0/0 and your 40th key would be at m/4/7 if the pattern keeps repeating.

Comment: For me the custom derivation key was m/0/14 then it went from m/1/0 to m/1/40 --- You will need to manually iterate through it to find matching public keys with another window open listing all the public address linked to the xpriv key. It took a good 1hr to do this.

Answer (score 7):

**How to transfer unspent Bitcoin Cash from Mycelium to Coinomi?**
or: How to identify the internal and external addresses which hold unspent output and transfer/sweep the funds to another wallet?
or: How can i get hold of my Bitcoin Cash?

*Be sure you know what you are doing with your private keys ;)*

Recommendation: Transfer your BTC funds from Mycelium to another wallet you have control of (e.g. Coinomi) and wait for the confirmations before starting to move your Bitcoin Cash

1. Go to https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/
2. Enter your 12 BIP39 Mnemonic words (or enter the extended private key)
3. (Default: Selected Derivation Path BIP44)
4. Use "External / Internal" Default which is: 0 (0=External) and scroll down to the first address of "Derived Addresses"
5. Hover over the private key to the right so the QR code shows up
6. Optional: Open second browser tab at http://blockdozer.com/insight/address/YOUR_ADDRESS where YOUR_ADDRESS is the address shown in the second column and display the BCC funds available - or enter the copied address in the search field
7. In your Coinomi BitcoinCash Wallet select .../Sweep wallet (... = upper right menu)
8. Scan private key QR code shown in 5)
9. Click "Next" to the lower right and wait for the funds to be retrieved (if there are some left at that address)
10. Continue with 5.) until your addresses have not been used (as seen in the blockdozer browser)
11. Scroll up on the BIP39 page and enter "External / Internal": 1 (internal - internal to Mycellium); If value = 1 in second loop go to 13.)
12. Continue with 5.) going back to first address shown
13. Wait for the transactions to be confirmed and the price to raise or sell or ShapeShift your new Bitcoin Cash to e.g. BTC

Please note: Presently Aug 14th, 2017 there is a bug in Coinomi related to scanning a Bitcoin Cash QR code. You should only copy/paste the Bitcoin Cash address into Coinomi and then you can select if it is a BTC or BCC address.

Additional background: coinomi.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/29000013719-how-to-get-bitcoin-cash-from-many-wallet-software-services-with-coinomi

Comment: Ok I followed these instructions.  The first address to come up is my HD account.  The problem is that it has a zero balance.  I have two "other accounts" aka addresses, that contain my entire balance. I've seached through 500 "derived addresses and none of them match the two that contain the supposedly contain the BTC on my wallet. I'm stumped.  I also tried https://steemit.com/btc/@libert/step-by-step-guide-on-claiming-bitcoincash-from-mycellium-wallet-201783t112141477z without any luck

Comment: Where do you see these 2 other accounts/addresses with the balance in there? With the same 12 BIP39 Mnemonic words related to this wallet in which you see the 2 addresses you should be able to derive the addresses as per above

Comment: @hortstu I had the same issue. When you switch the "External/Internal" input from 0 to 1, it shows the missing addresses. I assume that one set is for receiving from others, while the other series is for internal transaction. This is actually the most common place for remaining funds, as any payment you make will put the remaining funds on an internal address.