# How to trade BCC with Blockchain app and private key

Tags: private-key, bitcoin-cash, blockchain-wallet-app

There is something I do not understand.

I have handled a few bitcoin transactions using Android Blockchain app and imported private key. That worked and could buy/sell with btcdirect.eu (start transaction with btcdirect.eu and exchange bitcoin with Blockchain app)

Now after the hard fork I want to see my BCC and buy more of it, but how can I do that with my private key? If possible I want to use the Blockchain app.

Answer (score 1):

You can now access the Bitcoin Cash in your Blockchain wallet. See [here](https://blog.blockchain.com/2017/10/11/bitcoin-cash-bch/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have your private key (or the memnomics) you can use the BIP39 browser at https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/ to see the funds in your internal and external addresses.

More info on how to at [How to sweep private extended key from mycellium into coinomi for bitcoin cash coins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57422/how-to-sweep-private-extended-key-from-mycellium-into-coinomi-for-bitcoin-cash-c/)