# Can't restore Multibit HD 0.4.1 wallet into Electrum, Electron-Cash wallet for BCC

Tags: electrum, bitcoin-cash, multibit-hd

I've followed some advice from messageboards and stackoverflow on how to transfer my Multibit HD wallet into either of these 2 (Electrum, Electron-Cash) clients, and I keep coming up with 0 btc (before I drained my Multibit HD wallet) or bcc in both with no transactions or history. I have the password and all the wallet words for the Multibit HD wallet, but it seems like that's of no help.

The things I've tried:

1. Seed words into either client, BIP39 seed option checked, changed derivation to m/0', FAIL
2. https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/, put seed words into BIP39 Mnemonic, BIP32 tab selected, Multibit HD as the client selected, copy-paste BIP32 Extended Private Key into either client, FAIL
3. Same as 2, look through over 10,000 derived address to see if I could match any of the public addresses to ones in my wallet so I could write down the private keys, no derived addresses match the ones in my wallet, FAIL

Has anyone successfully obtained BCC from a pre-chain split Multibit HD wallet, or even transferred a wallet from Multibit HD 0.4.1 to Electrum (which would then be an easy copy to Electron-Cash)?

As a side note, I have sent all funds in the Multibit HD wallet to an Electrum wallet on another computer, so I'm free to experiment with the Multibit HD wallet without any risk of loss of funds.

I'd be willing to give the first person to successfully help me get the BCC, $25 of BCC as a little thank you. Not much, but then again I didn't have much Bitcoin to begin with :\

Comment: Look at the answer at https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57422/how-to-sweep-private-extended-key-from-mycellium-into-coinomi-for-bitcoin-cash-c/ to understand how to get hold of the addresses and how to sweep. If needed ask more.

Answer (score 1):

MultiBit HD uses a different derivation path from all other wallets; it does not use the BIP 44 standard for derivation paths. Thus you cannot use your MultiBit HD mnemonic or extended private key with other wallet software because they use different derivation paths and no wallet currently allows you to set an arbitrary derivation path.

The only way that I know of for you to get the MultiBit HD private keys is to use https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/. Enter your seed words, choose the BIP 32 tab, and choose the option for MultiBit HD. If you don't see your addresses, try toggling the Hardened Keys option and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I used multibit 0.5.1 how ever this could work:

1. Before fork, I moved bitcoins from multibit to Electrum by using multibit seed. I checked the BIP 39 option but did not touch derivation or other defaults.
2. Electrum wallet was created successfully with all bitcoins in it, however for some reason it was somehow 'seedless', in other words the 'seed' command in Electrum menu was greyed out. Otherwise normal send/receive capable wallet though.
3. Post-fork, moved bitcoins out of this wallet elsewhere and got bitcoin cash with following procedure:
   3.1 Export private keys from Electrum. This creates 2 lists of keys, only keep the longer ones.
   3.2 Create Electron Cash wallet from those keys by copy&pasting the list.
   result:
   *Bitcoin Cash wallet with correct amount of coins created*