# How do I move my bitcoin from mycelium to another wallet?

Tags: mycelium-wallet, sweep

I'd like to do this in a fee-less way.  This is the first step in claiming my BCH.  I've tried using this link

https://steemit.com/btc/@libert/step-by-step-guide-on-claiming-bitcoincash-from-mycellium-wallet-201783t112141477z

My bitcoins just never show up in the coinomi wallet.

I tried using this tutorial

[How to sweep private extended key from mycellium into coinomi for bitcoin cash coins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57422/how-to-sweep-private-extended-key-from-mycellium-into-coinomi-for-bitcoin-cash-c/57971#57971)

But the derived keys that are generated, and I've gone through at least 1000, are not for the "other addresses" that appear on my wallet.  The first in the list is my HD wallet but that has zero funds.  I have two "other addresses" with the BTC.  These don't appear. I only scanned the first 20 QR codes but searched 1000 for the prvt keys of the two addresses according to my backup.

Anyway I'll edit this if necessary I'm just trying to take this step by step.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://blog.btc.com/how-to-recover-your-trapped-bitcoin-cash-from-other-wallets-24b929543f26

Comment: I have not tried that yet, thank you. Before I do that though, I'm under the impression it's important to change addresses with my btc for security reasons. Then after that's done use the private key of the old address to claim my BCH using the previous addresses' key in a new wallet.   Since I asked this question,  I managed to figure out how to export from mycelium to coinomi but I was shocked to see a 6$ fee in the coinomi wallet.  I figured this isn't a transaction it would be fee-less.  I'm looking at other wallets now and still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

there should be an export function on mycelium. select the other keys on the left pane and export them. in coinomi, import them (dont sweep, that makes a transaction).

in coinomi, the import functiln appears to be under settings -> restore wallet. make sure you dont have anything of value in coinomi before restoring this way.

Answer (score 1):

To move your bitcoins just send to a different bitcoin wallet using the send option in mycelium. To get access to your bitcoin cash just restore from your mycelium seed in [electron cash](https://electroncash.org/). Electron cash is a bitcoin cash fork of electrum so the steps are the same [as for electrum](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-standard-wallet-from-seed/). Just make sure you select bip39 in step 4 and in step 5 choose legacy p2pkh as the derivation path.